# How does AWS Lambda handle concurrency?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda that queries a database for a count, and then submits to an SQS queue a number that represents an offset of a query that another lambda works on.  The second lambda is triggered by a push onto the queue.  If I set the concurrency to 10, does that mean the lambda will act like a threadpool and will continue restarting until the queue is empty?

Really accurate image of what I'm thinking about:
[image: lambda_flow_char]

Example 
Lambda A queries DB and finds that there are 10000 items in the table, so it submits 100 messages to the queue that go from 0 to 10000 in 100 chunks.

Lambda B has a concurrency of 10 and is triggered by puts in the queue, and each one pulls, does some work, and puts the result somewhere else and does whatever lambdas do after their job is done.  After they're all done, there's still 90 tasks left, does another pool of 10 start, or once a lambda is done another takes it's place?

Answer (score 3):

Since Lambda B has a concurrency of 10, then there will be a maximum of 10 Lambda functions running at any time.

When one Lambda function has completed, another will be triggered until there is nothing left in the SQS queue.

It is likely that AWS Lambda will create 10 Lambda containers, and each container will be re-used on subsequent calls.

See: [Understanding Container Reuse in AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/)